# How can I send the data fragment to fragment with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, fragment

I want to send the String data in LibraryFragment to LibrarySongFragment.

LibraryFragment :

```
public class LibraryFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public New onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mAdapter = new LibraryAdapter(options, context);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

LibraryAdapter :

```
public class LibraryAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MyModel, LibraryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ...
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String title = getItem(getAdapterPosition()).getTitle();
                    ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.library_coordinator, new LibrarySongFragment()).commit();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I want to send the title that in MyViewHolder in LibraryAdapter. You can see the "String title = getItem(getAdpaterPosition()).getTitle();". Just send to LibrarySongFragment and post it in fragment_song_library.xml TextView.

Comment: You want to only send the data or to attach a new Fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just create bundle of your data and set arguments in fragment object. i have modified your code. please refer

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String title = getItem(getAdapterPosition()).getTitle();

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                    Fragment fragment;

                    LibrarySongFragment librarySongFragment = new LibrarySongFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("KeyTitle",title);
                    librarySongFragment.setArguments(bundle);


                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.library_coordinator, librarySongFragment).commit();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**create inteface** 
in fragment from where you are going to send the data

```
SendMessage SM;

public interface SendMessage{
    void Senddata(String message,Boolean sent);
}
```

override this method to same fragment

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        SM = (SendMessage) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Error in retrieving data. Please try again");
    }
}
```

**implement this fragment to the activity which hold these fragment**

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements sendfragment.SendMessage
```

**override the message to the activity**

```
 @Override
public void Senddata(String message,Boolean sent) {
    fragtwo f = (fragtwo) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if(sent==true){
        Toast.makeText(this, "data transfered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        f.displaydata(message);
    }
}
```

**Create public method for sent data**

```
public void displaydata(String massage){
    String massageformat="received data is "+massage;
}
```

this is way to communicate between fragments in android

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand about the using interface.